# Higher than expected leakage drain current with Vgs=0 for N channel MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, leakage-current

I'm fiddling with an [STP36NE06, the datasheet](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/stmicroelectronics/5994.pdf) says for Vgs=0, worst case maximum drain leakage current should be 10uA. (Maximum Vds, maximum temperature)

[image]

However I'm getting a reading of just under 1mA (for Vds=5v, Tcase=25), only out by a factor of over 100! I've even soldered the gate and source directly to each other to make sure.

What's going on here?

Comment: Are you sure about the accuracy/resolution of your meter?

Comment: If those readings are real, they may be pointing towards electrostatic damage to the MOSFET. Can you substitute another one and test again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Max is 1uA at 25°C. Either your meter or your MOSFET is not doing what it should.

I would expect less than 100nA under those conditions.

1. Do you get ~1mA with a ~5K resistor?
2. Do you have the meter probes and switch in the correct position to measure current?